# Line-through not showing when clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to put a line through each ingredient as it is clicked. With the code I have below there is no line shown when I click it.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".recipe .ingredients .ing li").click(function(){
    $(this).css("text-decoration", "line-through");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="recipe">
  <div class="ingredients">
    <h3> Ingredients </h3>
    <ul class="ing">
      <li> 1 ripe banana </li>
      <li> 1/2 ripe avocado </li>
      <li> 1 tbsp cocoa powder </li>
      <li> 4 cups chocolate almond milk </li>
      <li> 4 pitted dates </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I just put your code in a snippet, without changing anything, and it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want the `line-through` to toggle.

If so, it's simpler to set up a style directive ...

```
.ing li.linethrough {
    text-decoration: line-through
}
```

... and use `.toggleClass()` :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".ing li").click(function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('linethrough');
    });
});
```

Even if you don't want a toggle action, it's still advantageous to restyle using a CSS directive.

*And fix the HTML as others have said*

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".ing>li").click(function () {
        $(this).css("text-decoration", "line-through");
    });
});
```

[Here is the **JSFiddle** demo](http://jsfiddle.net/owq4v6fn/)

Comment: OP's code already does this. Although your selector is likely to be faster.

Comment: @evolutionxbox I agree. The most likely cause is the invalid html code where the closing _div_ tag was missing, so _.recipe_ class was not found

Comment: But there is a closing div...

Comment: Also, why link of to jsbin, when stackoverflow has a snippet function, which does the same?

Comment: But its the closing div of ".ingredients" ...

Comment: Right. I missed that.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works once you make the html valid for me.

([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b6e95cj9/))

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".recipe .ingredients .ing li").click(function(){
    $(this).css("text-decoration", "line-through");
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="recipe">
    <div class="ingredients">
        <h3> Ingredients </h3>
        <ul class="ing">
            <li> 1 ripe banana </li>
            <li> 1/2 ripe avocado </li>
            <li> 1 tbsp cocoa powder </li>
            <li> 4 cups chocolate almond milk </li>
            <li> 4 pitted dates </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>                                                                                                                                                        <!-- jQuery --><script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```